# Unset HTTPS environment variable when X-Forwarded-Proto is http

Tags: apache, ssl, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, mod-ssl

I have endpoint termination setup on my Google Cloud Platform HTTP Load Balancer and HTTPS set as the protocol for communication with my backends.

This means that all requests, HTTP or HTTPS, is HTTPS to apache. The problem with this is that the `HTTPS` environment variable is set to `on` even when `X-Forwarded-Proto` is set to `http`.

All of my research and testing only points to the inverse case (setting `HTTPS` to `on` when `X-Forwarded-Proto` is `https` via a `SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on` rule).

But, *I need something to unset `HTTPS` when `X-Forwarded-Proto` is `http`.*

I've tried setting `SSLOptions -StdEnvVars` as well as many combinations of `SetEnvIf`, `SetEnv`, and `UnsetEnv`. Setting it via mod_rewrite is not an option for me (I don't know if it would work anyway). An interesting note about turning off `StdEnvVars` is that even when it is off, all the SSL related variables are gone except `HTTPS` and I can confirm nothing else is setting it in any of my config files.

**Edit:**

Some examples of directives I've tried in my server config, vhost, and htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto http HTTPS=Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto http HTTPS=0
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto http !HTTPS
SetEnv HTTPS Off
SetEnv HTTPS 0
SetEnv HTTPS
UnsetEnv HTTPS
```

Using these directives with other variables, including tests like `foo` works just fine.

Comment: Could you show some of the `SetEnvIf`, `SetEnv`, and `UnsetEnv` combinations you tried, so that our answers don't repeat experiments you've already tried?

Comment: @Castaglia Sure, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

> Using these directives with other variables, including tests like foo works just fine.

Just an idea first (gladly retracted if someone has a better idea)

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ says:

> #### Target proxies
>
> [Target proxies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/target-proxies) terminate HTTP(S) connections from clients, and
>   are referenced by one or more global forwarding rules and route the
>   incoming requests to a URL map.
>
> The proxies set HTTP request/response headers as follows:
>
> - Via: `1.1 google` (requests and responses)
> - `X-Forwarded-Proto: [http | https]` (requests only)
> - `X-Forwarded-For: <client IP(s)>, <global forwarding rule external IP>` (requests only)
>     Can be a comma-separated list of IP addresses depending on the X-Forwarded-For entries appended by the intermediaries the client is
>     traveling through. The first element in the  section
>     shows the origin address.

The question is where this is set. If in the apache config files, you could just alter the config. If it is set somewhere else, you need to find out where.

[The TargetHttpsProxies resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/targetHttpsProxies) did not list any ways to alter it either. So how about you post the config files that lead to above behavior?